# Save Multiple States and Restore to Each One

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

HTML5 `<canvas>` elements have a sort of save state mechanism, by repeatedly calling `cxt.save()` and `cxt.restore()`, where `cxt` is the `<canvas>`'s "context", gotten by, for example, calling `document.getElementById('my-canvas')`. However, I have not seen a way to save/restore to more than one state at a time. It seems that `<canvas>` has access to multiple states, as calling `restore` multiple times restores each respective "last" saved state.

Is there a way to jump back to before the "last" state without calling `restore` multiple times? Also, is there a way to go "forward" through the states? This would probably be easier to do if we could give each state a name, but I could work with ID's, if I needed to. In the end it would probably look similar to Adobe Photoshop's "layers" concept.

I would also take an answer that saves each state to a different variable, or that can copy the context without creating a whole new `<canvas>`. Copying functions like `angular.copy` do not seem to work with contexts, possibly because they are not technically objects; I believe they inherit from interfaces.

Finally, is this efficient? I am aware of how graphics-intensive `<canvas>` is, how taxing it can be on the client's computer. Is there a better way of manipulating the context without disrupting other parts of the canvas than implementing a layering system?

Answer (score 6):

**Some background:**

`context.save` and `context.restore` save and restore the context state. Context state includes styling, transformations, compositing, etc.

`.save` will push the current state on top of a stack. `.restore` will pop the last added state off the top of a stack. So they act as a last-in-first-out stack of states.

You can do multiple `.save` which will push multiple states onto the stack. Then you can pop multiple states off the stack by doing multiple `.restore`.

Since `.save` will save *all context state*, saves & restores are relatively expensive operations.

**An example of multiple save/restore:**

```
context.fillStyle='red';
context.fillRect(0,0,10,10);    // red rectangle
context.save();                 // fillStyle=='red'
context.fillStyle='blue';       // fillStyle='blue'
context.fillRect(0,0,10,10);    // blue rectangle
context.save();                 // fillStyle=='blue'
context.fillStyle='green';      // fillStyle=='green'
context.fillRect(0,0,10,10);    // green rectangle
context.restore();              // fillStyle='blue';
context.fillRect(0,0,10,10);    // blue rectangle
context.restore();              // fillStyle='red'
context.fillRect(0,0,10,10);    // red rectangle
```

**Answer#1:** No, there is no way to regress to prior saved states without executing multiple restores. The states are saved on a stack so unlike an array of states, you cannot "jump" to states[2].

**Answer#2:** In practice, it's much more common to not use save/restore, but rather to use javascript objects to store the **least state info as required**.

**For example:**

```
// put various fillStyles in a fills object
var fills={};
fills.red='red';
fills.green='green';
fills.blue='blue';

// create a function that draws a rect with specified fillStyle
function styledRect(x,y,w,h,fill){
    var priorFill=context.fillStyle;
    context.fillStyle=fill;
    context.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
    context.fillStyle=priorFill;
}

// use the fills object to control the fillStyle "state"
styledRect(0,0,10,10,fills.red);
```

**A more complex "state" object might look like this:**

```
buttonStyles={};
buttonStyles.normal={ font:'12px verdana', fill:'black' };
buttonStyles.warning={font:'12px italic verdana', fill:'orange' };
buttonStyles.danger={ font:'14px italic verdana', fill:'red' };

// example usage
someButtonDrawingFunction("You're in danger!",buttonStyles.danger);
```

Comment: This is essentially what I am doing, but now I have loops, and loops within loops, and it looks like this will be much more complicated now. Also, don't functions like `stroke()` and `fill()` work based on the current state, and style all shapes created with the same state, even if they were already drawn? How do you work around that without using different states?

Comment: I've updated the example styledRect function in my answer to show how you would "manually" save the minimum state being changed and "manually" restore the previous state. Yes, all strokes+fills work only on the current state and you only get 1 state per `beginPath` (the last declared state always wins).   If you want 2 different strokes or fills  then you must do 2 separate paths. ;-)

Comment: OK, so the values of the last begun path are used, not the last declared state. I still have a lot to learn about canvas.

Comment: The opposite! ;-). If you `beginPath` and declare 5 different `strokeStyle` then only the last strokeStyle will be used when you eventually call `stroke()`. You just get 1 styling per `beginPath` and the last declared style always wins. `fillRect` & `strokeRect` are actually path commands "under the covers", so only the last `strokeStyle / fillStyle` before fillRect or strokeRect will be used. Cheers!